# reference for drawing ramification figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to learn how to draw diagrams like [this one](https://ayoucis.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/formally-unramified-pdf-4.png?w=300&h=184) and [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Schematic_depiction_of_ramification.svg/300px-Schematic_depiction_of_ramification.svg.png). Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start.

I would appreciate all guidance. I prefer not to just dive blindly into a package like `tikz` which is why I'm hoping for guidance.

Comment: You will have to loose at least one eye if you want to learn to draw such things.

Comment: @percusse lose or loose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Three Branches

It's the weekend and I felt a bit like tinkering, so here's my attempt to more or less reproduce one of your two examples, with some color for contrast/clarification:

The position of the circles on the right side of the `crosspoint` is set by first extracting the intersection coordinate of two of the three paths, then marking the other path and the baseline at the same `x` coordinate as the intersection between the two upper paths (see the *bring reference to lower curve* comment).

[image: ramification figure with hobby library]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (crosspoint) at (4,-1);
    \draw[-latex,name path=first path]  (0,-2)   
        to[out angle=0,in angle=180,curve through={
            (2,-2.0) .. 
            (crosspoint) .. 
            (4.5,-0.25) .. 
            (6, 0.0)
        }
    ] (8,-0.5);
    \draw[-latex,name path=second path] (0, 0)   
        to[out angle=0,in angle=180,curve through={
            (2, 0.0) .. 
            (crosspoint) .. 
            (6,-2.0)
        }
    ] (8,-2);
    \draw[-latex,name path=third path]  (0,-1.5) 
        to[out angle=0,in angle=180,curve through={
            (2,-1.6) .. 
            (crosspoint) .. 
            (6, 0.2)
        }
    ] (8, 0);

    \fill [red, name intersections={of=first path and third path, by={a,b}}] 
        (a) circle (2pt)
        (b) circle (2pt)
        ;

    % Baseline and labels
    \coordinate (reference) at (0,-2.5);
    \draw [blue] (reference) -- ++(8,0);
    \fill [blue] (a|-reference) circle (2pt);
    \fill [blue] (b|-reference) circle (2pt);
    % Bring reference to lower curve
    \draw[opacity=0,name path=vertical reference] (b|-reference) -- (b);
    \fill[red, name intersections={of=second path and vertical reference, by={c}}] 
        (c) circle (2pt)
        ;

    % Labels on left
    \node[shift={(-0.1,0)}] (y) at (reference) {\footnotesize$y$};
    \node[shift={(-0.1,1.75)}] (x) at (reference) {\footnotesize$x$};

    % Could also do this with intersections, of course,
    % to cut off at the appropriate height.
    \draw (7,-2.45) -- ++(0,0.30);

    \node at (6.7,-2.25) {\footnotesize$f$};

    % Arrowhead
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm]}] (6.95,-2.45) -- (7,-2.45);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The solution uses [the Hobby package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby/hobby.pdf) for drawing the lines as cubic Bézier curves to make them look a bit nicer. If that is not acceptable/desirable, you can always draw the image with straight curve segments and a corner radius:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5mm]
    \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(1,1) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(1,-0.5) -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: straight segments]

---

Topics you might wish to look into [in the PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)/stuff I've used here:

- Arrows: p.182ff., `arrows.meta` library, p.202ff.
- The intersections library (p. 138ff., Section 13.3.2)
- The `-|` and `|-` operators: `-|` takes the horizontal components of the first coordinate, and the vertical component of the second coordinate, and `|-` does the analogous the other way around.
- relative coordinates: Section 13.4, p.140ff.
- "Syntax for Path Specifications", Chapter 14, p.146ff. (includes rounded corners in Section 14.5 on p.150ff.)
- "Actions on Paths", Chapter 15, p.164ff.
- The tutorials in Part I of the PGF manual might be worth a look if you're just starting out. They introduce most of the important concepts, and if you want to delve deeper, the PGF manual is heavily cross-referenced, so it's usually as easy as just clicking a command and jumping to its thorough documentation elsewhere in the pdf.
- If the curves have to fulfill some rigorous mathematical specifications instead of just being drawn through random points like my example, you can have a look at "Plots of Functions" (Chapter 22) in the PGF manual, or for more demanding tasks, the `datavisualization` command from Part IV of the PGF manual (p.756ff.), or [the pgfplots package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

---

I'm sure there are several ways in which the code could be optimized, but one has to start somewhere.

---

## Update: Two Branches

Since we can't use the intersection of two branches to mark the other branch as well as the baseline, we set a vertical helper line at `refb` 's `x` coordinate and mark the intersections of that helper line with the two branches, as well as its point on the blue baseline.

Set the helper line `opacity=0` to make it invisible; I've left it slightly visible here to illustrate the concept (the upper example uses the same idea, but with a different reference for the `x` coordinate; namely the `x` coordinate of the intersection of the two upper branches).

Adjust the horizontal position of the helper line and the intersection with the branches as needed by changing the `x` coordinate of `refb`.

[image: two branches]

Code (preamble is the same as above):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (crosspoint) at (4,-1);
    \draw[-latex,name path=first path]  (0,-2)   
        to[out angle=0,in angle=180,curve through={
            (2,-2.0) .. 
            (crosspoint) .. 
            (6, 0.0)
        }
    ] (8,-0.5);
    \draw[-latex,name path=second path] (0, 0)   
        to[out angle=0,in angle=180,curve through={
            (2, 0.0) .. 
            (crosspoint) .. 
            (6,-2.0)
        }
    ] (8,-2);

    \fill [red] (crosspoint) circle (2pt);

    % Baseline and labels
    \coordinate (refa) at (0,-2.5);
    \draw [blue] (refa) -- ++(8,0);
    \fill [blue] (crosspoint|-refa) circle (2pt);

    % Mark point on reference line and bring up to the two branches
    \coordinate (refb) at (6,-2.5);
    % Helper line. The red dots on the two branches will shift along the
    % branches as you adjust the helper line's x coordinate.
    % Change opacity to 0 to make line invisible again.
    \draw[opacity=0.2,name path=vertical reference] (refb) -- ++(0,2.6);

    \fill[blue] (refb) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red, name intersections={of=first path and vertical reference, by={a}}]
        (a) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red, name intersections={of=second path and vertical reference, by={b}}]
        (b) circle (2pt);

    % Labels on left
    \node[shift={(-0.1,0)}] (y) at (refa) {\footnotesize$y$};
    \node[shift={(-0.1,1.75)}] (x) at (refa) {\footnotesize$x$};


    % Could also do this with intersections, of course,
    % to cut off at the appropriate height.
    \draw (7,-2.45) -- ++(0,0.30);

    \node at (6.7,-2.25) {\footnotesize$f$};

    % Arrowhead
    \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm]}] (6.95,-2.45) -- (7,-2.45);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Glad to be of service. Have fun!

Comment: Dear alepnwasser, forgive me for bugging you. Using your marvelous answer I am trying to create a simpler ramification diagram featuring only two branches. I have deleted the 'third path' and also the line `(4.5,-0.25) ..`. This "loosens" the 'first path' a little so that the upper red circle no longer lies on it. How can I move this upper red circle down to lie on the 'first path' again? (It seems your solution actually uses this red circle to determine the one below it, so I am not sure what to do.) Many thanks!

Comment: @Arrow Yes, I can see how that would make things tricky; the `x` coordinate of the intersection between `first path` and `third path` is  used as a reference to mark the other points in the first example. I've added a two-branch example and some more explanations on how the whole thing actually works.

Comment: I really can't thank you enough. I'll start a bountry on this question when I can so that I can award your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Just for comparison, here is an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), where "Hobby" curves originally came from.

I'm relying on the [WP article that appears to be the source of the OP diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Ramification) for the semantics, so I hope my approach is appropriate.  I've started by defining the common points, then drawing the x-fibres through them, rather than drawing lines and looking for the intersections.  And I've tried to use the colors to emphasize the fact that this is supposed to be a map from *x* to *y*.

[image]

Here's the code, with what I hope are useful comments:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    % a variable for the width of the whole thing
    numeric wd;  wd = 240;

    % the paths we want
    path codomain, fiber[];

    % codomain is easy - just a base line
    codomain = (0,0) -- (wd,0);

    % to make the fibres, start by defining
    % common points that they pass through
    % note that we have nice implicit multiplication in MP, and fractions...
    z1 = (1/3 wd, 42);   
    z2 = (1/2 wd, 32);   
    z3 = (1/2 wd, 54);

    % % and some matching points on the co-domain line
    z4 = (x1,0);
    z5 = (x2,0);

    % start drawing from the back, with some dotted lines to link the matching
    % points
    draw z1 -- z4 dashed withdots scaled 1/4;
    draw z3 -- z5 dashed withdots scaled 1/4;

    % now define the fibers
    fiber1 = (0,32) {right} .. z1 {dir 40} .. z2 .. {right} (wd,48);
    fiber2 = (0,42) {right} .. z1 {dir-30} .. z2 .. {right} (wd,64);
    fiber3 = (0,64) {right} .. z1          .. z3 .. {right} (wd,32);

    % the "{right}" notation is the equivalent of TikZ in= and out= angles; here it
    % means "travelling right at this point", but it's quite general so you can put
    % any vector you want such as "{dir 40}" which gives a unit vector pointing at
    % 40° above the horizontal.  You can also leave them out.  As well as using the
    % directions at the start and finish, I've used them in the middle to tweak the
    % curves.   Now draw them...

    draw fiber1;
    draw fiber2;
    draw fiber3;

    % and mark some small circles at the key points
    fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z1;
    fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z2;
    fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z3;

    % and lets put a label at the left, 1/2 way between the start of fiber1 and
    % fiber3
    label.lft("$x$", 1/2[point 0 of fiber1, point 0 of fiber3]);

    % now change color to blue and draw the codomain and it's markers, and label
    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 blue);
    draw codomain;
    fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z4;
    fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted z5;
    label.lft("$y$", point 0 of codomain);

    % finally define another path for the mapping arrow, and draw & label that
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4 red);
    path map; map = 1/2[z1,z2] shifted 8 down -- ((x1+x2)/2,5); 
    drawarrow map;
    label.rt("$f$", point 1/2 of map);

    % tidy up neatly
    drawoptions();

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so compile this with `lualatex`, or work out how to adapt it for pdflatex with [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en), or for plain Metapost.